# How to print a LinkedList of objects

Tags: c++, printing, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to print out a linked list of stats objects. I have a stats class with a constructor that contains name, level and exp. But I can't get it to print out. This is the way I'm trying to do it:

```
void Print(DoublyLinkedList<Datatype> p_list)
    {
        int index = -1;
        //Set up a new Iterator.
        //DoublyLinkedListIterator<Datatype> itr = getIterator();
        for(itr.Start(); itr.Valid(); itr.Forth())
        {
                index++;
                cout <<"Index: "<< index << "\tElement: " << itr.Item() << "\n";
        }
        cout <<"Number of Elements in the List: " << m_count << endl;
    }
```

This causes the error on the cout of itr.item().
The error is:

`Error  1   error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Stats' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

This is from the doublyLinkedlist class and i set up a linkedList in the main() and I try doing list.print(list) from the main().

Edited in Stats.cpp

```
#include "Stats.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

Validators validators2;

Stats::Stats()
{
    firstName = "";
    secondName = "";
    level = 0;
    experience = 0;
}
Stats::Stats(string firstName,string secondName, int level, int experience)
{
    firstName = firstName;
    secondName = secondName;
    level = level;
    experience = experience;

}
    string Stats :: getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }
    string Stats :: getSecondName()
    {
        return secondName;
    }
    int Stats :: getLevel()
    {
        return level;
    }
    int Stats :: getExperience()
    {
        return experience;
    }
    Stats Stats :: input()
    {
        firstName = "Please enter the First Name: ";
        string inputfirstName = validators2.getString(firstName);
        secondName = "Please enter the Second Name: ";
        string inputSecondName = validators2.getString(secondName);
        cout<< "Please enter the level: ";
        int inputLevel = validators2.getNum();
        cout<< "Please enter the experience: ";
        int inputExperience = validators2.getNum();

        Stats s1(inputfirstName,inputSecondName,inputLevel,inputExperience);
        return s1;

    }
```

Thanks in advance... Becca.

Comment: If you show us the Stats class (and what you would like to print from it) it would be a little easier to help you.

Comment: I just edited in the stats class :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as it says: you don't have operator<< defined for your class Stats. You have to define this:

```
 std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Stats& s){
    //define what it means to cout<<Stats, for example:
    //print some attributes
    os<<"\nfirstName: "<<s.getFirstName();
    os<<"\nsecondName: "<<s.getSecondName();
    os<<"\nlevel: "<<s.getLevel();
    //and so on

    return os; // so chunk is possible os<<a<<b<<c
  }
```

Comment: Do i just put this into a function?  Do i have to pass it in anywhere ?  And thanks by the way :)

Comment: this can be defined outside if will not need an access to private members of your Stat class

Comment: I tried to put it in my DLL class and i just got a heap of errors:Error 1 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. 
Error 3 error C2804: binary 'operator <<' has too many parameters  DoublyLinkedList
Error 2 error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '&'

Comment: have you put semicolon? os<<s.std_dev();

Comment: nope i literally just copied and pasted it in as a function in my DoublyLinkedList class...

Comment: I assumed that you have mean() and std_dev() function. does your class have these functions?

Comment: Sorry no i though the where part of iostream.

Comment: Nearly there lol i have 2 errors: Error 1 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int 
Error 2 error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '&'

Comment: plaese update your code in question and show where are errors and most important how you use operator<<

Comment: Fixed it by moving it into a different file :)  The print fucntion looks like it has bugs but thats another days work haha thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

The error states exactly what is wrong - the operator **<<** does not know how to handle an object of the type you are trying to print. If you want to use the code like this, you have to overload the operator for the Stats class.

Comment: Well, not strictly *in* the class.

Answer (score 0):

In according to message you receive you just need to declare operator << for Stats type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Stats& s)
```

It should be free funton, not member of Stats